# set button active, when two editTexts are not empty

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to set my button active, only when two EditTexts are not empty. I try to use TextWatcher for that, but it doesn't really work fine - button stays active, even if erased all text from price input. Here is my code:

```
    final EditText titleEdit = findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText priceEdit = findViewById(R.id.price);
    final Button addButton = findViewById(R.id.add);


    titleEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleEdit.getText().toString().trim()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(priceEdit.getText().toString().trim()))
                addButton.setEnabled(true);
            else addButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

I tried few solutions from Stackoverflow, but it's still the same. What should I change in my code?

Comment: Currently what is your error

Comment: I run my app, button is disabled. I fill titleEdit and priceEdit - button is still disabled. After that - I fill some more to titleField, and only on this moment button gets enabled

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: @Aldres you can use onFocusChangeListener also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following variable as global variable

```
Boolean text1= false;
Boolean text2 = false;
```

Complete code

```
public class classname extends AppCompatActivity {

    Boolean text1= false;
    Boolean text2 = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Your code

        titleEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0 ){
                    text1 = true;
                    if(text1 && text2){
                        addButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                 }else{
                    text1 = false;
                    addButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() >0 ){
                    text2 = true;
                    if(text1 && text2){
                        addButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }else{
                    text2 = false;
                    addButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: text1 and text2 can't be accesed from TextWatcher

Comment: If it's final, you can't change its value

Comment: Yes create both of these as your class members @Aldres

Comment: @Aldres create these two variables as mentioned above code

Comment: Thank you! It works just right. I declared variables not in right place. That was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

- You should create Both **EditText** section **`TextWatcher`**.
- Check **`if (s.length()>0))`**

Try with

```
titleEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length()>0))
            {
             addButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
            addButton.setEnabled(false);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           if (s.length()>0))
            {
             addButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
            addButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: So, button will be enabled, only if two textWatchers are true?

Comment: I want my button to be active, only if two inputs are filled. This solution works only with one field.
But, when I start an app, button gets active, after any input was filled.

Comment: @Aldres create a global STRING/boolean variable, which checking this

Comment: something like Sushin Pv said below?

Comment: @Aldres you can follow.